# How to wait for a WebBrowser to actually display the document

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Note that this is **not** about waiting for it to load!

I'm building a HTML document in memory from a complex data structure.  For debug purposes I've been pushing the document to the display as I build the data structure--it's a **far** better way to inspect the data than trying to examine an array with several thousand elements in it.  Unfortunately the display routine appears to be asynchronous--and stopped by a breakpoint.  I update the display before the loop that's giving me trouble, the breakpoint fires and I'm looking at a blank screen.  Even a Thread.Sleep of a few seconds followed by a DoEvents isn't enough to get it to draw.

I would like some way to find out if it's actually been rendered.  Polling is fine, this is debugging, not production code.

(Note that the actual update consists of sending the string to the browser.  There are no secondary files being loaded, that is the whole thing.)